# Bitmap Screen around Cursor | CopyFromScreen

Tags: c#, bitmap

**What?**

I have an application that scans an image of my screen by a color code .

**Problem!**

This process takes too long , because the entire screen is searched.

**My Goal**

I would like the search to a region around the current mouse position.
But how do i do that?

**Code**

Here is my Code:

1. Creates a Screen

   ```
   private Bitmap CaptureScreen()
   {
      //Point a = new Point();
      //a = Control.MousePosition;   

       Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
       using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
       {
           g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), b.Size);
       }

       return b;
   }
   ```
2. Search for Color Code

   ```
   public Point GetPixelPosition(Color SearchColor, bool IgnoreAlphaChannel)
   {
       //Point a = new Point();
       //a = Control.MousePosition;


       _ColorFound = false;
       Point PixelPt = new Point(0, 0);

       using (Bitmap b = CaptureScreen())
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++)
           {
               if (this._ColorFound)
                   break;

               for (int j = 0; j < b.Height; j++)
               {
                   if (this._ColorFound)
                       break;

                   Color tmpPixelColor = b.GetPixel(i, j);
                   if (((tmpPixelColor.A == SearchColor.A) || IgnoreAlphaChannel)
                       && (tmpPixelColor.R == SearchColor.R)
                       && (tmpPixelColor.G == SearchColor.G)
                       && (tmpPixelColor.B == SearchColor.B)
                       )
                   {
                       PixelPt.X = i;
                       PixelPt.Y = j;
                       this._ColorFound = true;
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return PixelPt;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your way of scanning is very effective... but in this answer I'm aiming at doing exactly what you want, by using your code (I haven't optimized absolutely anything):

```
public Point GetPixelPosition(Color SearchColor, bool IgnoreAlphaChannel, int pixelsToSearchAround)
    {
        Point mousePosition = Cursor.Position;

        _ColorFound = false;
        Point PixelPt = new Point(0, 0);

        using (Bitmap b = CaptureScreen())
        {
            int minX = mousePosition.X - pixelsToSearchAround;
            int maxX = mousePosition.X + pixelsToSearchAround;
            int minY = mousePosition.Y - pixelsToSearchAround;
            int maxY = mousePosition.Y + pixelsToSearchAround;
            if(minX < 0) minX = 0;
            if(minY < 0) minY = 0;
            if(maxX > b.Width) maxX = b.Width;
            if(maxY > b.Height) maxY = b.Height;

            for (int i = minX; i < maxX; i++)
            {
                if (this._ColorFound)
                    break;

                for (int j = minY; j < maxY; j++)
                {
                    if (this._ColorFound)
                        break;

                    Color tmpPixelColor = b.GetPixel(i, j);
                    if (((tmpPixelColor.A == SearchColor.A) || IgnoreAlphaChannel)
                        && (tmpPixelColor.R == SearchColor.R)
                        && (tmpPixelColor.G == SearchColor.G)
                        && (tmpPixelColor.B == SearchColor.B)
                        )
                    {
                        PixelPt.X = i;
                        PixelPt.Y = j;
                        this._ColorFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return PixelPt;
    }
```

This should do what you are looking for in a very unoptimized manner: it's not what I'd do to search for a pixel component on screen.

You'd use the third parameter to determine how many pixels around the cursor to search for.

For further optimization, you could only capture the screen region that you are aiming to capture, but I'll leave that up to you (hint: instead of doing it in `GetPixelPosition`, you could do it in `CaptureScreen`, modifying the arguments to `g.CopyFromScreen`, instead of modifying the loop bounds).

Comment: `GetPixel` is incredibly slow. It always first constructs a 2d bitarray.

Comment: @CommuSoft I agree. I'd do it in an unsafe region... but if just defining a rectangle around the cursor is hard for the OP, I wouldn't like to go with pointers and such... I usually like to answser code that the OP can understand, then provide comments to try to get the OP investigate more, instead of providing "copypasteable code" (that's why I based my code on his then provided hints). Not that there's anything wrong with doing so, I just *personally* don't like to do it

Comment: You could also just `Marshal.Copy` the `BitmapData` to a managed array and do it "safe", but again, I wouldn't like to provide this kind of code to the OP unless he shows and proves he can understand it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of limiting the region, you can improve the performance of the color checking method.

Don't use `Bitmap.GetPixel`! Use `Bitmap.UnlockBits` instead.

```
public static unsafe Point GetPoint (Bitmap bmp, Color c) {
    BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits (new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    try {
        int s = bmd.Stride;
        int search = (c.A<<0x18)|(c.R<<0x10)|(c.G<<0x08)|c.B;
        int* clr = (int*)(void*)bmd.Scan0;
        int tmp;
        int* row = clr;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++) {
            int* col = row;
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++) {
                tmp = *col;
                if(tmp == search) {
                    return new Point(j,i);
                }
                col++;
            }
            row += s>>0x02;
        }
        return new Point(-1,-1);
    } finally {
        bmp.UnlockBits (bmd);
    }
}
```

This method returns `(-1,-1)` if the color cannot be found. You can adapt it to ignore the `alpha`-channel as well:

```
public static unsafe Point GetPoint (Bitmap bmp, Color c, bool ignoreAlpha = false) {
    BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits (new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    try {
        int s = bmd.Stride;
        int search = (c.A<<0x18)|(c.R<<0x10)|(c.G<<0x08)|c.B;
        if(ignoreAlpha) {
            search &= 0xffffff;
        }
        int* clr = (int*)(void*)bmd.Scan0;
        int tmp;
        int* row = clr;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++) {
            int* col = row;
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++) {
                tmp = *col;
                if(ignoreAlpha) {
                    tmp &= 0xffffff;
                }
                if(tmp == search) {
                    return new Point(j,i);
                }
                col++;
            }
            row += s>>0x02;
        }
        return new Point(-1,-1);
    } finally {
        bmp.UnlockBits (bmd);
    }
}
```

The reason `GetPixel` is slower is because **you don't process them in batch**. This is because the method always needs to decode the image and wait until the pixel you are querying walks by. Using `UnlockBits` you decode only once and then can iterate over all pixels.

Comment: Thank you!
Is there a way to check the Pixel next to the one the code found? I need to check that the pixel is the correct one.